# MediaWiki renderer in Java/Javascript supporting mathematical symbols and formulas

Tags: java, javascript, mediawiki, wiki-engine, wikipedia-api

I need a renderer/parser in Javascript or Java for MediaWiki syntax which supports mathematical symbols and formulas.

Comment: I found gwtwiki and Mylyn WikiText but they do not support formulas I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki uses AMS-LateX for its formulas:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Formula

There are plenty of renderers for mathematical LaTeX available in Java, eg. http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/, and JavaScript has eg. http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/ and http://www.mathjax.org/ as well.